# Numpy Pick subarrays with spcific column numbers

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have created a 3D point coordinates using numpy code:

```
xyzlist = np.mgrid[0:m,0:m,0:m]
points = xyzlist.reshape(3,-1).T
```

The points results are like

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,0],[0,2,1],[0,2,2],[0,2,3],[0,3,0],[0,3,1],[0,3,2],[0,3,3]........]
```

How can I pick the specific points with `y` = `1` or `3`or `5`...etc.(an odd number) and `z` = `1` or `3` or `5`...etc.(an odd number) ?
Namely the points array of `[[0,1,1],[0,1,3],[0,3,1],[0,3,3]]?`
Is there any simple way to do this in numpy because I have tons of points more than these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
points[((points[:, 1] == 1) | (points[:, 1] == 3)) & ((points[:, 2] == 1) | (points[:, 2] == 3))]
```

`points[:, 1]` is the 2nd column, `y`, and `points[:, 2]` is the 3rd column, `z`.